# How to concatenate only consecutive numbers in a string?

Tags: python, string, numbers, concatenation

I have a string with text and numbers, for example:

```
string = "Hello this is 123 456 a string for test 12 345 678. I want to merge 12 34 56"
```

And I want to have only the consecutive numbers together, like this:

```
newString = "Hello this is 123456 a string for test 12345678. I want to merge 123456"
```

How can I detect the number, check if they are consecutive and concatenate them?

Thanks!

Comment: I was trying first to get the numbers like:
string = "Hello this is 123 456 a string for test 12 345 678. I want to merge 12 34 56"
[int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using regular expressions:

```
import re
text = "Hello this is 123 456 a string for test 12 345 678. I want to merge 12 34 56"
newText = re.sub(r"(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)", '', text)
print(newText)
#'Hello this is 123456 a string for test 12345678. I want to merge 123456'
```

**Explanation**

What we're doing is replacing any spaces surrounded by digits with an empty string.

- `(?<=\d)` means positive look-behind for a digit (`\d`)
- `\s` means match a space character
- `(?=\d)` means positive look-ahead for a digit

Answer (score 3):

With `re.sub()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

s =  "Hello this is 123 456 a string for test 12 345 678. I want to merge 12 34 56"
result = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s+(\d+?)', '\\1\\2', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
Hello this is 123456 a string for test 12345678. I want to merge 123456
```